# Node.js - Changing html with a signal from Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, handlebars.js

There's a section in my website where users can subscribe to our mailing list. I want it so that:
1. Users will input and submit their emails.
2. Node.js will handle this request and add the email to our mailing list.
 
3. If the request was successful, it will show up in the front-end that the subscription was either successful or unsuccessful.

So what I don't get how to do is executing a front-end javascript process (the process that will alert to the user that the request was either successful/unsuccessful) through a signal from Node.js. I am a beginner in Node.js and I am lost.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I am trying to do this in a single-page. I do not want to redirect the user to a whole another page just to tell them that they were successfully subscribed. I just want a simple alert.

Comment: in node you can just response client request with something which let him know everything was ok. you can use status header or simply a response body. in your client you can create a jquery post

Comment: Check https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash

Answer (score 0):

You can create another page for the "Thank you" (in the case it was successful) and another one for a failed attempt. Handle it on the server and redirect them to the correct page (assuming you want to use different pages) Another thing you can do is create an empty `div` element for where you will put the status (successful of unsuccessful). When they submit the form and after you've handled the request, you can then re-render the page and pass in the message to put in your `div`.

Comment: What I wanted to do was having the form disappear and having this another div that is set as display:hidden right now to become display:block to replace the form that says "subscription was sucessful"!. This is very simple in jQuery. What I am looking for is, like an onClick function in a button, I could execute a javascript code in response to something, rather than an event in the front-end, but a process in the back-end. Thanks!